# Son has roughly 20 lice. Could he got them just yesterday?

Tags: lice

Just got a phone call from other parents where my son played yesterday and they informed me they have lice.

We used the anti lice shampoo and combed out roughly 20 lice, some of them clearly grown up.

Could it be that he got lice just yesterday? I would have thought that he only has a few lice then if he got them just yesterday? So I am wondering if he had lice for longer than just since yesterday.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's fairly unlikely that your son would have gotten that many head lice from one play session.  Head lice normally transfer from hair to hair contact, which tends to be fleeting enough that the normal mode of infection is a single louse that then lays eggs.  It's more likely that your son got infected a couple of weeks ago and most of the lice are grown up from having hatched on his head.

Make sure you are combing with a nit comb, clean the comb onto a clean white plate or paper towel, and see if you are combing out any louse eggs or nits.  Louse eggs are dark; hatched and dead eggs are white.  You can also examine his hair for nits.

You might want to inspect the rest of the family as well, and consider getting a professional inspection done.

Comment: Actually the color of nits often seems more related to the hair color than to their state (hatched).

Comment: Yep, if you combed out 20 in one sitting they've been breeding on him for a while. Keep combing once a day until you haven't found any for at least a week, and I very much agree it would be a good idea to have the rest of the family inspected as well.

Comment: @sbi The live ones may vary by hair color; they seemed to the time my family got lice, but they were too small to be sure; they are also very close to the hair root.  The hatched/dead ones are definitely white and further away from the scalp.  This is based on personal experience, when our whole hair color diverse family got lice.

Comment: Also, the eggs (nits) are *really* easy to miss so it's worth repeating the treatment 7 days after the initial one irrespective of if you think you need to or not and do a thorough check every week for at least the 3/4 weeks after as your child may have taken them to other settings like school etc and may catch them back.